# Inherit default behaviour for `Operator.draw`?

Tags: python, operator

`Operator.draw` doesn't seem to exist.

Is there a way to dynamically inherit the default drawing behaviour for `Operator()`s?

I'm aware that I can emulate the behaviour by, E.G., iterating through `.__annotations__` with `self.layout.prop()`. That's not a perfect mimic though, and I would prefer to reuse rather than duplicate built-in behaviour.

Comment: Do nothing? _eg_ add `bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}` and annotate simple op template

Comment: @batFINGER I still want to be able to do other things after/before the default behaviour. Maybe "inherit" isn't the right word— I want to *call* the default base method from the overridden subclass method, but there doesn't seem to be a method on the base class.